# Is "myriad" not prevalent in "day to day speech"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, expression-choice, uncountable-nouns

I have noticed people using "myriad" when they mean "uncountable" or simply many.

- Is "Myriad" not prevalent in "day to day speech
- Can it be used for definite but large amount of anything.

Comment: Wouldn't that be counter to the definition of myriad - `a countless or extremely great number`?

Comment: Because no one is sure how you should pronounce it.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen it to mean "10000".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would usually use a phrase like **"lots of" or "loads of"** instead.
>   You could still say "I've got myriad *problems*.

Some **usage examples** from major publications-

Unlike other Iraqi cities that are more ethnically and religiously uniform, Mosul is home to myriad communities.
(*Economist Apr 9, 2015*)

Its title ballad remains Mr. Bennett’s vocal signature to this day and, in his myriad renditions, has sold millions of copies.
(*New York Times Apr 7, 2015*)

Lake a myriad of tiny teeth in a saw, the transparencies came scavenging over the beach.
(*Lord of the Flies*)

This was the reality, and one could deal with it in a myriad of ways.
*(Long Walk to Freedom)*

We generated background studies, psychological assessments, daily chronologies, myriad facts and extrapolations.
(*Native Speaker*)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a fairly common expression in writing, as  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=myriad%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmyriad%3B%2Cc0) shows, and also in common speech. It is also used as an adjective, see usage note below:

n.

> - A large, indefinite number: a myriad of microorganisms in the pond; myriads of stars in the galaxy.
> - Archaic: Ten thousand.

adj.

> - Constituting a very large, indefinite number; innumerable: the myriad fish in the ocean.
> - Composed of numerous diverse elements or facets: the myriad life of the metropolis.

Usage Note:

> - Throughout most of its history in English myriad was used as a noun, as in a myriad of reasons. In the 1800s, it began to be used in poetry as an adjective, as in myriad dreams. Both usages in English are acceptable, as in Samuel Taylor Coleridge's "Myriad myriads of lives." This poetic, adjectival use became so well entrenched generally that many people came to consider it as the only correct use. In fact, however, both uses are acceptable today. (AHD)

(The free Dictionary.)